# Turn off video.js warning in browser console

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am seeing a lot of the following warning messages on the browser console. Is there a way to turn these off -

VIDEOJS: WARN: Player "product51154948" is already initialised. Options will not be applied.
video.js:16869 VIDEOJS: WARN: Player "product51154934" is already initialised. Options will not be applied.

Answer (score -2):

```
console.clear();
```

This will clear the the browser console. For all browser compatibility use

```
console.log("clear()");
```